# Populating column with NULL using windowing function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
  empid    claimid    flag    due_date
------------------------------------------
   123        777      Y        09/01/2023
   123        778      N         NULL
```

I'm trying to populate the `due_date` for the rows with `NULL` if the `empid` is the same, but the `claimid` is different. It would take the `due_date` if the flag = Y and the empid are the same.

The output would look like:

```
  empid    claimid    flag    due_date
 ------------------------------------------
   123        777      Y        09/01/2023
   123        778      N        09/01/2023
```

Code:

```
declare @t table 
           (
               empid int, 
               claimid int, 
               flag char(1), 
               due_date date
           )

  insert into @t
  values (123, 777, 'Y', '09/01/2023'),
         (123, 778, 'N', NULL)
```

I was thinking of using a window function but got stuck after this:

```
  select 
      *, 
      row_number() over (partition by empid order by due_date desc) as rownum
  from 
      @t
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Maybe something like `last_value(due_date) ignore nulls over (partition by empid order by due_date)`. (`ignore nulls` will require at least SQL Server 2022, I think). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Are there always only maximum two rows (one with `Y`, one with `N`) per empid? What to do if the row with flag = `Y` has no date?

Comment: If the row with flag = Y has no date then it should be left as NULL.  I haven't seen any cases where there can be more than 2 rows, but I'd have to assume there will be instances with more than 2.

Comment: So what should the result be if more rows appear with different dates? Can also be multiple rows per empid be `NULL`? You will need to explain the logic which date should be set in which case.

Comment: Sorry, there will never be more than one date value populated even if there are more than 2 rows.  The rest would just be null.  The goal is to get all the date values populated with the value in the row where flag = Y.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track to use a `window function`.

In comments you said there is always **one date only per empid**, all others are `NULL`.

So you can just use any window function that fetches this date and select it, for example `MAX`:

```
SELECT
  empid, claimid, flag,
  MAX(due_date) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY empid) AS due_date
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY empid;
```

Note: This is very "hard", you would also "override" dates if there are surprisingly multiple dates per empid.

If you want to explicitly override `NULL` values only, you can use `COALESCE` and set for example the latest date (using `MAX`) ...

```
SELECT
  empid, claimid, flag,
  COALESCE(due_date, MAX(due_date) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY empid)) AS due_date
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY empid;
```

...or the first date that is `NOT NULL` (using `FIRST_VALUE`).

```
SELECT
  empid, claimid, flag,
  COALESCE(due_date, FIRST_VALUE(due_date) IGNORE NULLS
    OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY empid)) AS due_date
FROM yourtable;
```

One last thing: You also mentioned in comments you want to take the date from the row where the flag is `Y`. One could read this comment as you want to do nothing in case the date column is `NULL` for flag = `Y`.
So we can add a `CASE` in above queries like this:

```
SELECT
  empid, claimid, flag,
  COALESCE(due_date, FIRST_VALUE(
    CASE WHEN flag = 'Y' THEN due_date END) IGNORE NULLS
    OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY empid)) AS due_date
FROM yourtable;
```

Try out all these things on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ev_Ne-yf), there you can see the differences between these options.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably stick to a correlated query in this scenario. Because you state there is only one unique date per empid you can use `top` and avoid any expensive sorts and spools, the following should perform very well.

```
select empid, claimid, flag, (
  select top(1) due_date from @t t2
  where t2.empid = t.empid and flag = 'Y' and due_date is not null
)due_date
from @t t;
```